# Python Json data Group it by same last name

Tags: python, json

Newbie here. I have a Json data that have full name, age, Country and Department. By using python, how can i generate a new Json format with last name as a key and the Json data contain the total number of people that have same last name, list of age and list of departments?

Json as data

```
{
  "John Jane": {
    "age": 30,
    "Country": "Denmark",
    "Department": "Marketing"
  },
  "Gennie Jane": {
    "age": 45,
    "Country": "New Zealand",
    "Department": "Finance"
  },
  "Mark Michael": {
    "age": 55,
    "Country": "Australia",
    "Department": "HR"
  },
  "Jenny Jane": {
    "age": 45,
    "Country": "United States",
    "Department": "IT"
  },
  "Jane Michael": {
    "age": 27,
    "Country": "United States",
    "Department": "HR"
  },
  "Scofield Michael": {
    "age": 37,
    "Country": "England",
    "Department": "HR"
  }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
{
  "Michael": {
    "count": 3, // number of people that have same last name,
    "age": {
      "age1": 55,
      "age2": 27,
      "age3": 37
    },
    "Country": {
      "Country1":"Australia",
      "Country2":"United States",
      "Country3":"England"

    },
    "Department": {
      "Department1": "HR",
      "Department2": "HR",
      "Department3": "HR"

    },
    
   ...
   ...
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: The result is invalid, keys cannot be duplicated.

Comment: Use dictionary for different 'age' ? not a list ?

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view, using `dict` for 'age', 'Country' or 'Department' is not necessary and more complicate, using `list` should be better.

```py
import json

text = """{
  "John Jane": {
    "age": 30,
    "Country": "Denmark",
    "Department": "Marketing"
  },
  "Gennie Jane": {
    "age": 45,
    "Country": "New Zealand",
    "Department": "Finance"
  },
  "Mark Michael": {
    "age": 55,
    "Country": "Australia",
    "Department": "HR"
  },
  "Jenny Jane": {
    "age": 45,
    "Country": "United States",
    "Department": "IT"
  },
  "Jane Michael": {
    "age": 27,
    "Country": "United States",
    "Department": "HR"
  },
  "Scofield Michael": {
    "age": 37,
    "Country": "England",
    "Department": "HR"
  }
}"""

dictionary = json.loads(text)
result = {}
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    last_name = key.split()[1]
    if last_name in result:
        result[last_name]['count'] += 1
        result[last_name]['age'].append(value['age'])
        result[last_name]['Country'].append(value['Country'])
        result[last_name]['Department'].append(value['Department'])
    else:
        result[last_name] = {'count':1, 'age':[value['age']], 'Country':[value['Country']], 'Department':[value['Department']]}

print(result)
```

```
{'Jane': {'count': 3, 'age': [30, 45, 45], 'Country': ['Denmark', 'New Zealand', 'United States'], 'Department': ['Marketing', 'Finance', 'IT']}, 'Michael': {'count': 3, 'age': [55, 27, 37], 'Country': ['Australia', 'United States', 'England'], 'Department': ['HR', 'HR', 'HR']}}
```

Comment: Noted for your opinion. Thanks